# Draw custom routes in google map in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

How can I draw custom routes between two destinations which is not connecting with a road?

For example, if the **Source** is The Pizza Factory and the **Destination** is ATI Solutions I have to draw route like this but there is not roads to connect these two place.

[image]

I tried Google's Polylines code but it provides waypoints on the roads only.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?origin=%@,%@&destination=%f,%f&sensor=false&waypoints=optimize:true&mode=driving", @"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json", getmycurrlat, getmycurrlong, LATI, LONGI];
    NSLog(@"my driving api URL --- %@", urlString);
    NSLog(@"you clicked on button %ld", (long)sender.tag);
    NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", urlString]];
    NSURLResponse* res;
    NSError* err;
    NSData* data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] returningResponse:&res error:&err];
    if (data == nil) {
        return;
    }

    NSDictionary* dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSDictionary* routes = [dic objectForKey:@"routes"][0];
    NSDictionary* route = [routes objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
    NSString* overview_route = [route objectForKey:@"points"];

    GMSPath* path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:overview_route];
    GMSPolyline* polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
    polyline.strokeWidth = 5.f;
    polyline.map = self.mapView;
```

All helps are appreciated!!

Comment: map preferred standard way to make routs is on roads with appropriate space to pass away, what kind of custom route you want to make ?

Comment: There is no road connecting between pizza factory and ATI solution only there is a space between two buildings. Is there any possible way to draw line something like in snapshot?

Comment: in my exp map will only create route on connected roads if you provide static `lat` `long` prior but there is dynamic way also to create routs bet source to dest while moving [have a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422826/how-to-track-a-users-location-and-display-the-path-travelled-using-google-maps).

Comment: Is there any way to create custom waypoints?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @FabKremer No..

Comment: @Manigandasaravanan thanks for the response! I believe I'll end up using polylines from the GMaps SDK, by wrapping up all coordinates needed to build the custom path and draw some kind of smooth custom path.

Answer (score 0):

Try this is works for me, hope it helps you, i am using AFNetworking to get data

```
    NSString *url1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=%@&destination=%@&mode=driving",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",self.locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude,self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude],pickLoc];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *operationManager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [operationManager POST:url1
                parameters: nil
                   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                       // NSLog(@"JSON: %@", [responseObject description]);

                       NSArray *routesArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"routes"];

                       GMSPolyline *polyline = nil;

                       if ([routesArray count] > 0)
                       {
                           NSDictionary *routeDict = [routesArray objectAtIndex:0];
                           NSDictionary *routeOverviewPolyline = [routeDict objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
                           NSString *points = [routeOverviewPolyline objectForKey:@"points"];
                           GMSPath *path = [GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:points];
                           polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
                           polyline.strokeWidth = 3;
                           polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9607 green:0.0358 blue:0.1529 alpha:0.6];
                           polyline.map = self.viewMapView;
                       }
                   }
                   failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
                   }
     ];
```

Comment: This will draw polyline on roads. But I need to draw polyline on non road areas.

Comment: you can see the routsArray and set your own custom lat long as per your route and make the polyline

Comment: route array will provide only the waypoints of roads. But I need waypoints of non-roads. Please check the above image.